# X_flatten in numpy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

If someone explain me this . How below code is working.

It is mentioned in [Neural Networks and Deep Learning from coursera](https://dskvkwvsoepcycphszrtce.coursera-apps.org/notebooks/Week%202/Logistic%20Regression%20as%20a%20Neural%20Network/Logistic_Regression_with_a_Neural_Network_mindset_v6a.ipynb)

A trick when you want to flatten a matrix X of shape (a,b,c,d) to a matrix X_flatten of shape (b×c×d, a) is to

```
X_flatten = X.reshape(X.shape[0], -1).T # X.T is the transpose of X
```

Assume i have X=(209,64,64,3) , then when i say

`X_flatten = X.reshape(X.shape[0], -1).T`

which means

```
X_flatten = X.reshape(209, -1).T
```

How it is working , I am really confused about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume the shape of x is (209,64,64,3).

Then `x.reshape(209, -1)` will turn it into shape (209, 12288), since it will reshape to have 209 rows and will automatically figure out how many columns are needed (here: 64*64*3 = 12288 columns).

`x.reshape(209, -1).T` will simply transpose this, so that x has the final shape (209, 12288).

Comment: After the transpose, won't the final shape of X be (12288, 209)?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am concerned, the `reshape(209, -1)` will flatten the `(64, 64, 3)` to `64, 64 * 3`, then to `64 * 64 * 3`. You can do a test as below:

```py
stacked_matrix = np.arange(10).reshape(2, 5)
print(stacked_matrix.reshape(1, -1)
# 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```